# How to pass the context from a view and access the context data in javascript in Django?

Tags: django

I am passing some data in a dictionary in django view and I want to access the dictionary data in my javascript code to display the data in my html. But whenever I print the passed context, it just prints 'success' on my console and not the actual data.

Here is my dictionary structure:
context['search_successful'] = "some string"
I am passing this dictionary to my success function after making an ajax call to the view. For the time being I am just passing the HTTPResponse('true', context).

After collecting the data in my javascript code, I just want to print the data of my context which will give 'some string' on my console but it gives success everytime.

Here is my view:

```
def daily_object_search(request):
    context = {'search_successful': "No"}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        object_name = request.POST['search_object_name']
        print("The query for search :", object_name)
        if len(object_name) <= 2:
            print("The length of the object name :", len(object_name))
            return HttpResponse('invalid_query')
        my_cursor = mydb.cursor()
        sql = "select * from education_fruits where tag = '" + object_name + "'"
        my_cursor.execute(sql)
        result = my_cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
        if my_cursor.rowcount <= 0:
            print("No object found")
            return HttpResponse('false')
        context['search_successful'] = "Yess"
    return HttpResponse('true', context)
```

Here is my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit', '#search_object', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url 'daily_object_search' %}',
            data: {
               search_object_name: $('#search_my_object').val(),
               csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: function(data, context){
                if(data == "true"){
                    alert('This Object is Present');  
                    /* Print the context data by creating a html tag and appending the context information to a <h1> tag by doing document.id.innerHTML = context['search_successful']*/                                 
                    console.log(context);
                }
                else if(data == "invalid_query"){
                    alert("Please enter a valid object to be searched");
                }
                else{
                    alert('This object is not present');
                }
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

The console should give me something like 'search_successful : Yes' or 'search_successful : No' but gives me success everytime. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The context dictionary can be pass to `render` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), I cannot find a reference to context in `HTTPResponse` in the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects

If you want return a complex value return a json as content in the response.
You are setting the content always as `true` (harcoded) so in fact doesn't distinguish any case, that be unuseful in my opinion.

I suggest you to use status code to differentiate the various situations, like `invalid_query`, that seems a `400 Bad Request`, or `No object found`, i.e. `404 Not Found`. In this case you should use the error handler in you ajax call to capture this negative response.

If you like to stay with the success handler only, you can use a json like this:

```
{ 
'result': 'invalid_query'
}
```

so in the case you will want to pass the fetched elements, you can add a key in the json